# Selenium-Webdriver with ruby can't click to choose selection of TokenInput

Tags: jquery, ruby, selenium, jquery-tokeninput

I now trying to write an automated web content downloader using Selenium-Webdriver and ruby language.  My target site has a query form with TokenInput, so I need to handle well, not only just send strings.

I googled and found a [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842464/how-to-test-token-input-fieldfrom-jquery-token-input-plugin-using-selenium) and a [code snipet](https://gist.github.com/jtanium/1229684).  Unfortunately I'm a newbie of Ruby world and I have less knowledge about cucumber, so I want to use Selenium-Webdriver directly.

The gist mentioned above describes a basic concept to handle TokenInput, so I wrote a small code like this:

```rb
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30

driver.get("this is sample url")

elem_id = "<id of elements>"
str = "Japan" # for example

ti_field = driver.find_element(:id, "token-input-#{elem_id}") # now find the token-input
ti_field.send_keys(str)
sleep(2) # just for test

# find an item which picked by TokenInput, and click it
driver.find_elements(:css, ".token-input-dropdown").each do |item|
  p item.text
  p item.text.include?(sent_string)
  item.click if item.text.include?(str)
end
```

Using this code, I can put string "Japan" in the field, but can't select an item which picked by TokenInput.  It seems that the "item" ignore my "click" request.

I need your help.  Please let me know which is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write my environments. Operating system: Ubuntu Utopic 64bit, Ruby: 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux] with rbenv, Firefox: 32.0+build1-0ubuntu2, Selenium-Webdriver: latest Gem (2.43.0)